# How to make one div scrollable and other unscrollable using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap template which will be contain two divs, from which one div the left-one should be fixed and the right one should be scrollable, similar to the http://www.trulia.com. I have tried the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="">
    </div><!--Fixed one-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div><!--Scrollable-->
</div>
```

Comment: Here's something a little more durable with browsers that support `vh`: http://jsfiddle.net/1Ldr7L70/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will solve your problem

```
.col-md-6:nth-child(1){
  position:fixed;
}

.col-md-6:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px; // Set this height to the appropriate size
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It save my hours. :) (y)